# Is there a faster alternative to using the arrow keys?

Tags: keyboard, rstudio, keyboard-shortcuts

I regularly code in R, and I just realized how much of a pain it is for me to move my hand down to the arrow keys and then back to they letters on the keyboard. In Rstudio, I have to do this regularly because the studio completes certain synax automatically, (like parentheses and quotation marks) and then I have to press the arrow key to move out of the parentheses (or quotation marks), this then removed any possible advantage from having R complete the syntax for me. This is extra costly for me because I'm left handed. Is there a shortcut for the arrow keys that's closer to the letter keys?

Comment: Use vim instead of rstudio :)

Comment: Or there is actually a better solution. Type quotation mark or closing parenthesis in the place where it's got autocompleted - it will replace autocompleted entity. That way you don't have to use arrow keys.

Comment: Or turn on Vim keybindings in RStudio :-)

Answer (score 33):

### Intro

To do this, you have two approaches in front:

1. use your own code
2. use 3rd party softwares

In this answer I introduce the most efficient and easy approach, so for some OSs it's easy and efficient to write your own code while in others it's not really efficient and need a harsh work which have no achivement but wasting time

### Windows users - approach 1: using Microsoft PowerToys

1. install powertoys from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/install)
2. open it and from sidebar menu go to "Keyboard Manager"
3. under "shortcuts" section click on "Remap a shortcut"
4. for "Physical Shortcut" sections you should add "Alt(Left)" and "L" and for "Mapped To" section you should type "Right"
5. do step 4 again respectively for other key remaps you want
6. click on "okay"
   that's it, you ready to go

### Windows users - approach 2: using autohoykey

In this method you will use:

- <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> instead of <kbd>↑</kbd>
- <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> instead of <kbd>↓</kbd>
- <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> instead of <kbd>←</kbd>
- <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> instead of <kbd>→</kbd>

In order to use this feature, these are the steps in your way:

1. Download and install [autohotkey](https://autohotkey.com)
2. Right-click in your desktop area then go to new and make a new "notepad" file
3. Open empty notepad file and copy/paste codes below into that
4. Rename your notepad file eveything you want but with *.ahk format
5. Click your file to run your script

Now you can enjoy and never use arrow keys again...

```
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

; AHK Command       ; key   = Effect        (Description)

; ALT Keypress Implied for all below

!i::Send {UP}       ; i UP          (Cursor up line)
!k::Send {DOWN}     ; k DOWN            (Cursor down line)

!j::Send {LEFT}     ; j LEFT        (Cursor left one character)
!l::Send {RIGHT}    ; l RIGHT       (Cursor right one character)

!h::Send {HOME}     ; h     ALT + RIGHT (Cursor to beginning of line)
!;::Send {END}      ; ; ALT + LEFT  (Cursor to end of line)

!u::Send ^{HOME}    ; h     SHIFT + HOME    (Cursor to beginning of document)
!o::Send ^{END}     ; o SHIFT + END (Cursor to end of document)

; CTRL + ALT Keypress Implied for all below

!^j::Send ^{LEFT}   ; j     CTRL + LEFT (Cursor left per word)
!^l::Send ^{RIGHT}  ; l CTRL + RIGHT    (Cursor right per word)

; SHIFT + ALT Keypress Implied for all below

!+i::Send +{UP}     ; i SHIFT + UP  (Highlight per line)
!+k::Send +{DOWN}   ; k SHIFT + DOWN    (Highlight per line)

!+j::Send +{LEFT}   ; j SHIFT + LEFT    (Highlight per character)
!+l::Send +{RIGHT}  ; l SHIFT + RIGHT   (Highlight per character)

!+h::Send +{HOME}   ; h SHIFT + ALT + LEFT  (Highlight to beginning of line)
!+;::Send +{END}    ; ; SHIFT + ALT + RIGHT (Hightlight to end of line)

!+u::Send ^+{HOME}  ; u SHIFT + CTRL + HOME (Highlight to beggininng of document)
!+o::Send ^+{END}   ; o SHIFT + CTRL + END  (Hightlight to end of document)

; SHIFT + CTRL + ALT Keypress Implied for all below

!+^j::Send +^{LEFT}     ; j SHIFT + CTRL + LEFT (Highlight per word)
!+^l::Send +^{RIGHT}    ; l SHIFT + CTRL + RIGHT    (Hightlight per word)

!+^i::Send +!{UP}   ; i SHIFT + ALT + UP    (Multiply cursor up)
!+^k::Send +!{DOWN} ; k SHIFT + ALT + DOWN  (Multiply cursor down)

; CTRL + SHIFT Keypress Implied for all below

+^i::Send +^{UP}
+^k::Send +^{DOWN}
```

#### Important Notes

To use autohotkey script which you made, every time you turn on computer instead of clicking on your script every time, you can copy your script in startup folder.

How to find startup folder?

1. <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
2. type: **shell:startup**
3. copy your script into that Folder

### MacOS users

In this method you will use

- <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> instead of <kbd>↑</kbd>
- <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> instead of <kbd>↓</kbd>
- <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> instead of <kbd>←</kbd>
- <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> instead of <kbd>→</kbd>

Use [hammerspoon](https://www.hammerspoon.org/): Is a tremendous tool for many purposes (not just assign a keybinding, for example you can use it for windows sanping or ...) and I think that is one of the MUST-HAVE tools in any macos

Since the documentation of hammerspoon is very very straightforward, I just put the code here and you can install and config hammerspoon from it's [Getting Started with Hammerspoon](https://www.hammerspoon.org/go/)

```
hs.hotkey.bind({"alt"}, "I", function()
  hs.eventtap.keyStroke({}, "up")
end)
hs.hotkey.bind({"alt"}, "K", function()
  hs.eventtap.keyStroke({}, "down")
end)
hs.hotkey.bind({"alt"}, "J", function()
  hs.eventtap.keyStroke({}, "left")
end)
hs.hotkey.bind({"alt"}, "L", function()
  hs.eventtap.keyStroke({}, "right")
end)
```

#### Important Notes

If you think hammerspoon is slow or not working as genius as you want another option is [Karabiner](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/)

### Debian-based Linux users (not Ubuntu; see important notes):

In this method you will use:

- <kbd>CapsLock</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> instead of <kbd>↑</kbd>
- <kbd>CapsLock</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> instead of <kbd>↓</kbd>
- <kbd>CapsLock</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> instead of <kbd>←</kbd>
- <kbd>CapsLock</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> instead of <kbd>→</kbd>

and

- <kbd>alt_gr</kbd> instead of <kbd>CapsLock</kbd>

How? Well:

1. open up Terminal, write your keyboard layout on in a file(I named it modmap), then open that file and edit it as you will follow next steps:

   ```
   xmodmap -pke > modmap
   gedit modmap
   ```
2. change keyCode 108 (alt_Gr/ISO_Level3_Shift) value, so it should be like this after modifying:

   ```
   keycode 108 = Caps_Lock Caps_Lock Caps_Lock Caps_Lock Caps_Lock Caps_Lock
   ```
3. change keyCode 66 (CapsLock) value, so it should be like this after modifying:

   ```
   keycode  66 = Mode_switch Mode_switch Mode_switch Mode_switch Mode_switch Mode_switch
   ```
4. change keyCode 31 (i) value, so it should be like this after modifying:

   ```
   keycode  31 = i I Up NoSymbol NoSymbol NoSymbol NoSymbol NoSymbol
   ```
5. change keyCode 44 (j) value, so it should be like this after modifying:

   ```
   keycode  44 = j J Left NoSymbol NoSymbol NoSymbol NoSymbol NoSymbol
   ```
6. change keyCode 45 (k) value, so it should be like this after modifying:

   ```
   keycode  45 = k K Down NoSymbol NoSymbol NoSymbol NoSymbol NoSymbol
   ```
7. change keyCode 46 (l) value, so it should be like this after modifying:

   ```
   keycode  46 = l L Right NoSymbol NoSymbol NoSymbol NoSymbol NoSymbol
   ```

#### Important Notes

1. xmodmap is no longer used/supported on Ubuntu (because it wasn't handy for many users, I think they stop using xmodmap from 2013) but since this is a professional question for very fast coding and working with computer and also coding, I see many professionals using Debian or their own debian-based Linux (not Ubuntu) and they always prefer native solutions to plugins or...
   Anyway if you are using Ubuntu you can use xkb or gnome tweak tools where you maybe can adjust your keyboard mapping in a GUI
2. You can't use this solution easily if you got multi langs/inputs on your keyboard, but you can use it like below:

   - <kbd>CapsLock</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> instead of <kbd>↑</kbd>
   - <kbd>CapsLock</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> instead of <kbd>↓</kbd>
   - <kbd>CapsLock</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> instead of <kbd>←</kbd>
   - <kbd>CapsLock</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> instead of <kbd>→</kbd>

for example, if you also want to have *persian_language_input* you can do step 1,2,3 above then change other steps like below:

```
keycode  31 = i I Arabic_heh Up 5 6 7 8
keycode  44 = j J Arabic_teh Left 5 6 7 8
keycode  45 = k K Arabic_noon Down 5 6 7 8
keycode  46 = l L Arabic_meem Right 5 6 7 8
```

be careful that you shouldn't test above keyboard shortcuts in Terminal

1. Since we're using `xmodmap` tool (because it's native unlike xkb), You can only change the AltGr keysyms for keycodes that are already using AltGr. So we change it with CapsLock to overcome this problem since CapsLock is more comfort for fingers to find it is a very acceptable solution.
2. In most cases, alt_Gr is the right alt Key on your keyboard

further reading about xmodmap [on ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xmodmap#Keymap_table)

if anyone has knowledge about this answer in BSD OS (or BSD-BASED) I'll appreciate that if he/she add it to my answer

Comment: Hammerspoon is quite slow, I would not consider it as a solution

Comment: @nick318 well it's actually working perfect in my macbook-pro-2019-mvvk2, maybe it's about your system or your inappropriate version of hammerspoon. after all i think it's worth to think that maybe it's your problem instead of a 7.2k stared project on github

Comment: @nick318 use vim editor and configure it to using jkli instead of arrow keys just for programming you can use vim editor which is actually more professional than every other code-editor but your problem is still a pit if you want using jkli instead of arrow keys in other places like IDEs or in your whole OS.

Comment: @nick318 anyway i will find a **native** way for this purpose in macos whenever i have time and will update this post again

Comment: @nick318 ok, you can consider karabiner as an alternative now, link is in description

Comment: `xmodmap` is available in Ubuntu [at least since 2018](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/xmodmap.1.html). Of both, on Wayland only works `xcb`

Answer (score 2):

Two weeks back Microsoft launched "Power Toys" in the Microsoft Store.
You can use the keyboard manager to create a shortcut for arrow keys as mentioned in answer.
I use the vim shortcut for arrow keys as shown below:

[added shortcuts for arrow keys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9syJ.png)
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9syJ.png): [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9syJ.png]

Answer (score 0):

New Script working with Autohotkey v2:

```
; Since the comments mention the effect and description of each hotkey, I'm keeping only the hotkey definitions for brevity.

; SetWorkingDir has changed in v2. You now directly assign to A_WorkingDir.
A_WorkingDir := A_ScriptDir

; ALT Keypress Implied for all below
!k::Send("{UP}")
!j::Send("{DOWN}")
!h::Send("{LEFT}")
!l::Send("{RIGHT}")

; CTRL + ALT Keypress Implied for all below
!^h::Send("^{LEFT}")
!^l::Send("^{RIGHT}")

; SHIFT + ALT Keypress Implied for all below
!+k::Send("+{UP}")
!+j::Send("+{DOWN}")
!+h::Send("+{LEFT}")
!+l::Send("+{RIGHT}")


; SHIFT + CTRL + ALT Keypress Implied for all below
!+^h::Send("+^{LEFT}")
!+^l::Send("+^{RIGHT}")
!+^k::Send("+!{UP}")
!+^j::Send("+!{DOWN}")

; CTRL + SHIFT Keypress Implied for all below
+^k::Send("+^{UP}")
+^j::Send("+^{DOWN}")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I have the same pain, I've tried to use hjkl as arrow keys, and some layout like fun plus wsad. But now I have gotten the best solution since I got a Filco Minila-R. It divided space key into three keys, two function on two sides of sapce key. Like when I type right arrow, I hold the left fn key (at the left side of space) with my left hand thumb while touch  F key, F key always used for locating for left hand.
e-d-f-s plus left function keys achived up-down-right-left, right function plus jm-k,-l. achived ins del-home end-pu pd.
If I use capslock + hjkl, I have to use two hands, Minila-R layout allows me using one sigle hand to touch this keys, besides, the two functions which devided from space key just at the most fine place for thumb to touch.